# C# serialize class with unmanaged data

Tags: c#, serialization

I am currently modifying my code so I could serialize it using the built-in .NET Binary serializer. However a problem occured with one of the class`s fields - a pointer to struct, which is in the unmanaged memory (created via p/invoke). It appears that .NET just remembers the pointer value while serializing, rather than the values, and when I deserialize the class the Matrix property has always random data. Below you could find a sample of my code:

```
[Serializable]
public unsafe class FrequencyMatrixBuilder
{
    public SparseMatrix* Matrix { get; private set; }
    ....
}

[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct SparseMatrix
{
    public int rows;
    public int cols;
    public int vals;
    public int* pointr;
    public int* rowind; 
    public double* value;
};
```

Any suggestions how can I resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into custom serialization by implementing the ISerializable interface. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Yeah, but can I use the ISerializable interface only for SparseMatrix struct, so the class FrequencyMatrixBuilder serializes by default and only SparseMatrix is serialized manualy?

Answer (score 3):

Have your class implement the [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) interface and handle the serialization manually as you see fit.
And don't forget to add the appropriate constructors for deserialization.

Comment: Yeah, but can I use the ISerializable interface only for SparseMatrix struct, so the class FrequencyMatrixBuilder serializes by default and only SparseMatrix is serialized manualy?

Comment: No, it's the other way around (well, almost). `FrequencyMartixBuilder` needs to implement the interface, and `SparseMatrix` doesn't, because you will serialize it manually anyway. The problem is, you're absolutely right, with the pointer. The runtime doesn't know how to serialize the pointer field, because it does not have clear semantics. That is, it could be pointing to a single structure, or to an array of structures, or to a linked list of structures, or a million other options. The only one who knows what is actually there is you. Therefore, you have to handle the serialization.

Comment: I meant, can .NET automatically serialize all FrequencyMatrixBuilder properties, except for Matrix which I will serialize manually?

Comment: Ah. No, I'm afraid it can't.

To fix this, you could use aggregation: put the Matrix field into a separate structure and include that structure in the FrequencyMatrixBuilder in place of the Matrix field. Then you can make that extra structure implement ISerializable and serialize just that field, while all other Builder's fields will be taken care of automatically. At the same time, the physical memory layout of your Builder structure will remain the same, so that your unmanaged code will be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [serialization surrogates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx#S1): they provide a good alternative to implementing ISerializable when you cannot or do not want to mix serialization logic with the business logic of the class (in your case, SparceMatrix).